# ipsec.conf leftsubnet different than actual subnet

Tags: ipsec, strongswan

I've been tasked with troubleshooting an ipsec.conf and I'm having difficulty understanding a specific portion of the configuration. Specifically, I cannot figure out why this config is using a different leftsubnet than the actual subnet my server is running on. Here's an example:

```
left=10.1.10.50
leftid=<a public IP address>
leftsubnet=192.168.1.15
right=<public IP address of remote system>
rightid=<same ip as right>
rightsubnet=<same ip as right/32>
```

My organization doesn't use any of the 192.168.*.* address space, so I'm not sure why this address is present. I've looked at the manual pages for ipsec.conf, but their description of leftsubnet isn't particularly useful in my case:

> private subnet behind the left participant, expressed as network/netmask (actually, any form acceptable to ipsec_ttosubnet(3)); Currentlly, IPv4 and IPv6 ranges are supported. if omitted, essentially assumed to be left/32, signifying that the left end of the connection goes to the left participant only

Has anyone seen a configuration that is setup in a similar way?

Comment: Is this for a host-host connection? Or a host-subnet connection? Is there any NAT involved? Is that IP installed on any of the interfaces of that host (check with `ip addr`)?

Comment: @ecdsa This is a host to host connection. I'm not performing any NAT that I'm aware of (is this something I can check directly on the Linux box?).

Comment: Check `iptables -L -t nat` to see possible NAT rules, but since it's a host-host connection that's probably not the case. Also check if the IP is installed on the host. Since that host is apparently behind a NAT this might be a static virtual IP to simplify routing on the other end (instead of using 10.1.10.50, which might change, a static fixed inner tunnel IP is used).